# nginx php-fpm 7.3 file not found on php files

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now. I've tried a million different suggested configs online, nothing seems to work. Here's where i'm currently at.

Loading any .php file just shows "File Not Found". The file exists, it's got the correct permissions, and I've verified that it's being passed the correct script name and path.

```
    server { 

    listen 443 ssl; 
    root /var/www/html/example/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm ;
    server_name example.tk; 
    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf; 
    client_max_body_size 0; 

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here is the include:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffers 512 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1m;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 4m;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 4m;
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
#fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_SCHEME    $scheme;
fastcgi_param HTTPS             $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY        "";
fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME       $server_name;
fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS   200;
```

translated path is commented out because someone said somewhere that it was causing all the problems. I noticed no change with or without it.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu and all the programs from scratch. works now.